# Is it bad practice to have a unique_ptr member that has a raw pointer accessor?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a class that has a unique_ptr member, and this class retains sole ownership of this object. However, external classes may require access to this object. In this case, should I just return a raw pointer? shared_ptr doesn't seem to be correct because that would imply that the accessing class now shares ownership of that memory, whereas I want to make it clear that the original class is the sole owner.

For example, perhaps I have a tree class that owns a root node. Another class may wish to explore the tree for some reason, and requires a pointer to the root node to do this. A partial implementation might look like:

```
class Tree
{    
public:
    Node* GetRoot()
    {
        return m_root.Get();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> m_root;
};
```

Is this bad practice? What would a better solution be?

Comment: "Another class may wish to explore the tree *for some reason* (...)" I believe that whether or not this is a good idea depends on that reason. Please do not design your classes without use cases.

Comment: In your example code, there's no way to `reset()` the `unique_ptr`, so it's no better or worse than it would be to return a pointer to a non-static data member of the class. That may or may not answer your question, depending whether you have an opinion on the good/badness of that. In real code there probably are operations that you can perform on the `Tree` that reseat `m_root` to refer to a different object, so any user who has called `GetRoot()` has to worry about whether they call any such functions. If they can avoid that, then the fact it's a `unique_ptr` introduces no further problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more normal implementation might be for the `Tree` to expose iterators or provide a `visit` mechanism to explore the tree, rather than exposing the implementation details of the `Tree` itself. Exposing the implementation details means that you can never change the tree's underlying structure without risk of breaking who-knows-how-many clients of that code.

If you absolutely insist there's a need for this, at least return the pointer as `const`, such as `const Node* GetRoot() const` because external clients should absolutely not be mutating the tree structure.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. If I have an iterator or some kind of visitor to the structure, that visitor needs some way of knowing what current node it's on - such as a pointer to that node, right? Or is there a different way to implement this pattern? If it does need a pointer to its current node, then I'm wondering if it would be best practice to have that as a raw pointer or not.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Meyers, *Effective C++* Item 15 says yes, although the primary reason is for interactivity with legacy code.  If you are in a controlled environment - e.g. a startup where there is little legacy code and it's easy to extend a class as needed or in a homework assignment - there may be little need and it may only encourage using the class incorrectly.  But the more reusable approach is to expose raw resources.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that when people say "avoid pointers" they really mean "use ownership semantics", and that pointers are not inherently bad.

Returning a non-owning pointer is an acceptable way of getting references that may also be null and isn't anymore dangerous than the alternatives. Now, in your case this would only make sense if your tree was meant to be used as a *tree*, rather than using a tree internally such as `std::map` does.

It's uncommon to do this though as usually you'll want the pointers and resources abstracted away.